# Call Vuex action from component after mutation is complete

Tags: vue.js, asynchronous, vuex, store

I have a Vue component that calls a Vuex action in its `create` hook (an `api.get` that fetches some data, and then dispatches a mutation). After that mutation is completed, I need to call an action in a different store, depending on what has been set in my store's state... in this case, `getUserSpecials`.

I tried to use `.then()` on my action, but that mutation had not yet completed, even though the `api.get` Promise had resolved, so the store state I needed to check was not yet available.

Does anyone know if there is a 'best practice' for doing this? I also considered using a watcher on the store state.

In my component, I have:

```
  created () {
   this.getUserModules();
    if (this.userModules.promos.find((p) => p.type === 'specials')) {
     this.getUserSpecials();
    }
  },

methods: {
   ...mapActions('userProfile', ['getUserModules',],),
   ...mapActions('userPromos', ['getUserSpecials',],),
},
```

In my store I have:

```
const actions = {
  getUserModules ({ commit, dispatch, }) {
  api.get(/user/modules).then((response) => {
   commit('setUserModules', response);
  });
 },
};

export const mutations = {
 setUserModules (state, response) {
  Object.assign(state, response);
 },
```

};

Right now, the simple `if` check in my `create` hook works fine, but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

> [1] Your action should `return` a `promise`

```
getUserModules ({ commit, dispatch, }) {
  return api.get(/user/modules).then((response) => {
   commit('setUserModules', response);
  })
}
```

> [2] Call another `dispatch` when the first one has been `resolved`

```
created () {
  this.getUserModules().then(response => {
    this.getUserSpecials()
  })
}
```

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. The way I was doing it before I wasn't returning a promise

Answer (score 0):

### Make your action return a promise:

**Change:**

```js
      getUserModules ({ commit, dispatch, }) {
      api.get(/user/modules).then((response) => {
       commit('setUserModules', response);
      });
     },
```

**To:**

```js
    getUserModules({commit, dispatch}) {
       return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            api.get(/user/modules).then((response) => {
                commit('setUserModules', response);
                resolve(response)
            }).catch((error) {
                reject(error)
            });
        });
    },
```

**And then your `created()` hook can be:**

```js
      created () {
       this.getUserModules().then((response) => {
            if(response.data.promos.find((p) => p.type === 'specials'))
                this.getUserSpecials();
       }).catch((error){
        //error
       });
      },
```